# bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar added into classpath unnecessarily

Tags: java, maven

In my project I am using dependency in POM which is given below :

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.69</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I am building the code I can see below jars added into my classpath:
bcprov-jdk15on-1.69.jar
bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar

I do not want **bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar** in my classpath but I am not sure from where It is being added.
Can anyone help me to get rid of this ?

Comment: Then add an exclusion to whatever dependency is pulling it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mvn dependency:tree` to see, where transitive dependencies are coming from.

Once identified, you can add an `<exclusion>` to the `<exclusions>` tag of the first-level dependendency.